# How can I redirect/ rewrite all urls that contain a certain string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, joomla-sef-urls

this has had me stumped for a few days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I think htaccess is probably the best way to do what I need, but if you have a different sdolution I'm glad to hear it.

I am using joomla as my CMS and right now I have a .htacces file right now that will take all urls and send them to the community component of my site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user='$1' [L]


# RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?cb_username=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

However this will redirect every page Url that doesn't have a directory or file associated with it.

What I need is for the htaccess file to only redirect  URLS if they contain the string "community/profile/user"

I still consider myself a noob, and I have spent many days already trying to fix this problem.

Hopefully someone else can shed some light on the issue here.
Below is the complete code of my .htaccess file

```
 ##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 1005 2006-10-05 18:00:00Z stingrey $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2006 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##
Options +FollowSymLinks
#
# mod_rewrite in use
#
RewriteEngine On
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update YourJoomlaDirectory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /

#
# Rules
#
#
# ProfileRedirector V 1.3
#
# Make sure your host allows option override
# and has ModRewrite installed

# activate Rewrite enginge

RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user='$1' [L]


# RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?cb_username=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should remove the double `RewriteBase` and `RewriteEngine`.

Now, did you mean something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)community/profile/user/(.*)$ index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user=$2 [L]
```

The first Rewrite shouldn't change a thing about the path of all the image files. If the URL contains `community/profile/user/` then it rewrite the url to `index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user={what-comes-after-user/}`

You should be very carefull on what you write with .htaccess because a simple space or a missing capital can end up in a fatal error not loading any pages.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help.I tried this, but it gives me a 404 error for ever page other that the default home page. I realize now that I have asked the wrong question.

Comment: MY profiles are located under community/profile/user/"username"  I need the htaccess file to do nothing unless a URL containing "community/profile/user" is found. if that string is found then it should chanhe the link to mysite.com/"username" but really be showing the page index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user=$2            Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Ah I see. You are trying to redirect AND rewrite. It's not possible  to use the method you want because mysite.com/username will block any other subpages, like mysite.com/contact will redirect to the user "contact". The easier way to do is RewriteRule to "/usr/$2" [R] and then RewriteRule "/usr/(.*)" to index.php?...